# I'm trying to get results returned from bash for each line returned to console from an aws cli call. Please advise

Tags: amazon-web-services, suse, sles

I'm trying to collect all the Instances in an AWS region (describe-instances) and then grep certain lines out of the specific AMI's (describe-images) for each instance found with the first command. I don't want to dump it to a file first.

```
for AMI in "aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}'";
do "aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $AMI |grep '"Name"\|ProductCodeId\|ProductCodeType'";done
```

What is wrong with my syntax? Thank you!

The Error: 
ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-000:~> ./Get-Instance-Meta.sh 
./Get-Instance-Meta.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `aws'
./Get-Instance-Meta.sh: line 4:`aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}';'

First command output expected:

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-000:~> grep ImageId | aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}'
ami-02bf6f88fab67448b
ami-0d59109fccbbc4da2
ami-01a80cb1b7a431fb9
ami-0d86f04dd6dfc89df
```

Second command output expected:

```
ec2-user@ip-172-31-20-214:~> aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids ami-01a80cb1b7a431fb9 |grep '"Name"\|ProductCodeId\|ProductCodeType'
                    "ProductCodeId": "51luq5gebk3opt7gcvkdrrm89",
                    "ProductCodeType": "marketplace"
            "Name": "OpenSUSE_Leap15.1TaskcatPython3_",
```

I'm basically looking across all instances for ProductCodeID or ProductCodeType of 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative to your first command using [--query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output.html#cli-usage-output-filter):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
    --region=us-east-1 \
    --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].ImageId' \
    --output text
```

Then for the `for` loop:

```
AMIs=$(aws ec2 describe-instances \
        --region=us-east-1 \
        --query 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].ImageId' \
        --output text)  

for AMI in ${AMIs};    
do 
   echo ${AMI}

   aws ec2 describe-images \
       --image-ids ${AMI} \
       --query 'Images[*].[Name, ProductCodeId, ProductCodeType]' \
       --output text

done
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used the wrong quotes.

```
"aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}'"
```

isn't executed. You will have to use backticks `` or `$()` instead of `"` to quote your command. e.g.

```
$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}')
```

`$()` means that you return the output of the command as arguments. `"` means that what is quoted is one long argument, which doesn't seem to be what you want. In you second use of `"` you want the output to be printed to the console as usual, so you can omit the `"` entirely. Putting this together you get:

```
for AMI in $(aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P 'ami.{0,18}');
do aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $AMI |grep '"Name"\|ProductCodeId\|ProductCodeType';done
```

Comment: thanks.  I've tried every combination thereof. Sane error on unexpected token aws

`for INSTANCE in ``aws ec2 describe-instances --region=us-west-2 |grep ImageId |grep -o -P ami.{0,18}``
do 
    ``aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids $INSTANCE |grep   .Name.\|ProductCodeId\|ProductCodeType``
done'